# Swift - How to call method from a specific instance?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, macos-carbon

I am currently developing an iOS app using the [CarbonKit](https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit) library for navigation. I currently have a `UITableView` in the first tab, and I want to programatically navigate to another tab when a cell is selected.

I have implemented the following function under my main `CarbonKit` view controller:

```
import CarbonKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate {


    func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIViewController      {

        switch index {
        case 0:
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AircraftViewController") as! AircraftViewController
        case 1:
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadController") as! LoadController
        case 3:
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsController") as! SettingsController
        default:
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerOne") as! ViewControllerOne
        }   
    }

    func navigate(index: UInt) {
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setCurrentTabIndex(index, withAnimation: true)  
    }

}
```

`setCurrentTabIndex` is the function provided by the library to programatically switch tabs.

In my `UITableViewController` I have the following:

```
import UIKit
import CarbonKit

class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        \\ First Attempt
        (ViewController() as CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate).navigate(2)

        \\ Second Attempt
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("controller") as! ViewController
        viewController.navigate(2)
   }

}
```

I understand that with my first attempt I created a new instance of `ViewController` and my second attempt didn't select the instance I was hoping for.

How can I best activate the method in the first instance of `ViewController` from `SecondViewController`?

Comment: You need to hang on to a reference to the `CarbonTabSwipeNavigation` you create. I'm guessing you set everything up in your app delegate. Where do you implement the `carbonTabSwipeNavigation: viewControllerAtIndex` protocol method? I suspect that would be a good place to set a property with the `CarbonTapSwipeNavigation` for each child view controller. Then you can use that property in your `SecondViewController`.

Comment: I implement `viewControllerAtIndex` in the above `viewController` class. How do I set a viewController as a property? I have updated my question with the aforementioned `viewControllerAtIndex` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding a `CarbonTabSwipeNavigation` property to your `SecondViewController` class, so you will have access to your navigation provider:

```
import UIKit
import CarbonKit

class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {
    weak var carbonNavigation : CarbonTabSwipeNavigation?;

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
       if let carbonNav = self.carbonNavigation {
           carbonNav.setCurrentTabIndex(index, withAnimation: true)
       }
   }

}
```

Next up we need to set that `carbonNavigation` property, so it will be available for use. It looks like your `CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate` is a nice place to do that. On a side note, I don't see your `SecondViewController` ever being returned by your delegate - is that intended?

```
import CarbonKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate {


    func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAtIndex index: UInt) -> UIViewController      {

        switch index {
        case 0:
            let aircraftVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AircraftViewController") as! AircraftViewController
            aircraftVC.carbonNavigation = carbonTabSwipeNavigation
            return aircraftVC
        case 1:
            // do something similar, instantiate view controller, set navigation property
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoadController") as! LoadController
        case 3:
            // do something similar, instantiate view controller, set navigation property
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsController") as! SettingsController
        default:
            // do something similar, instantiate view controller, set navigation property
            return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerOne") as! ViewControllerOne
        }   
    }

    func navigate(index: UInt) {
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setCurrentTabIndex(index, withAnimation: true)  
    }
}
```

You could also add a `ViewController` property instead of a `CarbonTabSwipeNavigation` and expose all of the methods you need from Carbon as methods in `ViewController`. That would mean changing the type of the property declaration and setting it to `self` instead of `carbonTabSwipeNavigation`.

Comment: Seems like you may want `weak var` to avoid a strong reference cycle

Comment: For the initial post, I changed the name of the `AircraftViewController` class to `SecondViewController` for simplicity and forgot to change it when I updated my post. Otherwise that works as I was hoping. I wasn't expecting to declare my variable in the second view controller. Is there any resource you recommend for learning the intricacies of Cocoa and Xcode alongside Swift? Thanks again so much for your help!